# Simple IRC Bot in C#

Tags: c#, .net, networking, chat

This was a simple IRC bot I threw together a long time ago, found recently, and was curious as to if there were any kind of significant improvements that could be made.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

public class IRCbot
{
    // server to connect to (edit at will)
    public static string SERVER = "irc.changeme.com";
    // server port (6667 by default)
    private static int PORT = 6667;
    // user information defined in RFC 2812 (IRC: Client Protocol) is sent to the IRC server 
    private static string USER = "USER IRCbot 0 * :IRCbot";
    // the bot's nickname
    private static string NICK = "IRCbot";
    // channel to join
    private static string CHANNEL = "#opers";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        NetworkStream stream;
        TcpClient irc;
        string inputLine;
        StreamReader reader;
        StreamWriter writer;

        try
        {
            irc = new TcpClient(SERVER, PORT);
            stream = irc.GetStream();
            reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
            writer.WriteLine("NICK " + NICK);
            writer.Flush();
            writer.WriteLine(USER);
            writer.Flush();

            while (true)
            {
                while ((inputLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("<- " + inputLine);

                    // split the lines sent from the server by spaces (seems to be the easiest way to parse them)
                    string[] splitInput = inputLine.Split(new Char[] {
                        ' '
                    });

                    if (splitInput[0] == "PING")
                    {
                        string PongReply = splitInput[1];
                        //Console.WriteLine("->PONG " + PongReply);
                        writer.WriteLine("PONG " + PongReply);
                        writer.Flush();
                        //continue;
                    }

                    switch (splitInput[1])
                    {
                        case "001":
                            writer.WriteLine("JOIN " + CHANNEL);
                            writer.Flush();
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }

                // close all streams (to preserve memory)
                writer.Close();
                reader.Close();
                irc.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // shows the exception, sleeps for a little while and then tries to establish a new connection to the IRC server
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            string[] argv = {};
            Main(argv);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- you should separate the `IRCBot` from the `Main` into its own class with it's own fields/properties
- you should specify all required parameters via the construtor so that it is not possible to create an invalid ircbot
- I don't think it's a good idea to make the retry recursive - IMHO it would be better to create a loop and limit the retries so that you don't have an infite loop (ok, unless it was desired)
- you really should use the `using` statement. In your current implementation the resources will be closed only if there was no execption - if an exception occurs the `Close`es won't be called. You also don't free the resources because you don't call the `Dispose`, you just close them and then create new resources on retry, this is a memory leak.

Here's an example:

```
public class IRCbot
{
    // server to connect to (edit at will)
    private readonly string _server;
    // server port (6667 by default)
    private readonly int _port;
    // user information defined in RFC 2812 (IRC: Client Protocol) is sent to the IRC server 
    private readonly string _user;

    // the bot's nickname
    private readonly string _nick;
    // channel to join
    private readonly string _channel;

    private readonly int _maxRetries;

    public IRCbot(string server, int port, string user, string nick, string channel, int maxRetries = 3)
    {
        _server = server;
        _port = port;
        _user = user;
        _nick = nick;
        _channel = channel;
        _maxRetries = maxRetries;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        var retry = false;
        var retryCount = 0;
        do
        {
            try
            {
                using (var irc = new TcpClient(_server, _port))
                using (var stream = irc.GetStream())
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine("NICK " + _nick);
                    writer.Flush();
                    writer.WriteLine(_user);
                    writer.Flush();

                    while (true)
                    {
                        string inputLine;
                        while ((inputLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("<- " + inputLine);

                            // split the lines sent from the server by spaces (seems to be the easiest way to parse them)
                            string[] splitInput = inputLine.Split(new Char[] { ' ' });

                            if (splitInput[0] == "PING")
                            {
                                string PongReply = splitInput[1];
                                //Console.WriteLine("->PONG " + PongReply);
                                writer.WriteLine("PONG " + PongReply);
                                writer.Flush();
                                //continue;
                            }

                            switch (splitInput[1])
                            {
                                case "001":
                                    writer.WriteLine("JOIN " + _channel);
                                    writer.Flush();
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // shows the exception, sleeps for a little while and then tries to establish a new connection to the IRC server
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                retry = ++retryCount <= _maxRetries;
            }
        } while (retry);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
void Main()
{
    var ircBot = new IRCbot(
        server: "irc.changeme.com",
        port: 6667,
        user: "USER IRCbot 0 * :IRCbot",
        nick: "IRCbot",
        channel: "#opers"
    );

    ircBot.Start();
}
```

Comment: Yeach, and extract connection info in separate data structure. Then We should separate responsibility - connection, looping and answer strategy -> move this to separate classes. Ideally would be ```using(var client= clientFactory.Create(Clients.IRC, clientCredentials)){  await botStrategyFactory.Create(BotStrategy.PingPong, client.StreamToRead, client.StreamToWrite).RunAsync();  }```  :D

Comment: @tym32167 I agree, usually I'd separate everything but this is so _tiny_ that I'd probably wouldn't bother.

Comment: oh, that was just joke, I agree with KISS (Keep it simple and stupid), we don want to overcomplicate here, you answer is pretty enough.

Answer (score 12):

In addition to [t3schb0t's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/142674/13424) I'd also change your parsing logic. Your code is just few lines and it's already too complicate to read. After you moved code into a separate class then it's time for refactoring!

Abstract away read/write/log logic. You already have `StreamReader`, `StreamWriter`, `Console` and `TcpClient`. **Current implementation is hard to test** (because you need a TCP server and you must read data to/from streams.) More than that: it's almost impossible to test in isolation...let's introduce few more classes.

Abstract `IrcServerConnection` to handle connection (with its implementation `TcpIrcServerConnection` and probably a mock to test all the other logic without a true remote IRC server).

Now you have to abstract input stream, let's introduce a `IrcDataPipe` (here I'd avoid to call it *channel* because it may cause confusion with IRC channel but a better name is required...) It may expose `ReadLines()` (which returns `IEnumerable<string>`, an *infinite* loop until connection is closed may be appropriate), `WriteLine()` for generic write operations and `Send()` to explicitly write a command (see later.) If required you may want to introduce two *views* of this pipe accessible through two properties like `Request` and `Response` (but I'd not go too far at the beginning.)

Also note that `NetworkStream` is not buffered then you do not need to call `Flush()` after each write.

You may want to introduce a `Log` class with its `LogWriter` (which may be console by default). In this way you may also differentiate between errors and informative messages. Console output may be, for example, colored and you may want a different format for file log (note that command line redirection is always possible.)

`inputLine.Split(new Char[] {' '});` may be simplified to `inputLine.Split(' ');`

Be consistent with variable naming, `PongReply` should be `pongReply`.

I'd suggest to remove all those *magic constants*. If you do not want to introduce an `IrcCommand` class you may at least use constants. Here is how I'd like to see it (at first step):

```
pipe.Send(new PongCommand(splitLine[1]));
```

I'd simplify parsing. For commands for which you have a mandatory response you may use a dictionary (or Reflection...) For example a generic `IrcCommand` derived class may be something like this:

```
[InResponseTo(IrcServerMessages.Ping)]
sealed class PongCommand : IrcCommand {
    public override string GetResponse(IrcServerMessage message) {
        return message.Parameters.Single();
    }
}
```

As you can see I introduced an `IrcServerMessage` class which both hide parsing and encapsulate parameters. Your *processing loop* will be as simple as:

```
using (var connection = CreateConnection().Open())
using (var pipe = connection.OpenPipe())
{
    LogIn(pipe);

    foreach (var message in pipe.ReadLines().Select(x => new IrcServerMessage(x))
        ProcessKnownMessages(message);
}
```

Where `LogIn(pipe)` is something like this:

```
private static void LogIn(IrcPipe pipe) {
    pipe.Send(
        new NickCommand(_nick),
        new UserCommand(_nick)
    );
}
```

Note multiple commands on the same line (`Send(params IrcCommand[] commands)`) to denote a *batch* which I want to fail/succeed all together.

Now let's move connection into a separate method to use your class like this:

```
using (var connection = new IrcConnection(CreateConnection))
using (var bot = new IrcBot(connection) {
    connection.Open();
    bot.StartChatting();
}
```

You may automatically start bot when connection is open (just add a `ConnectionStateChanged` event in your `IrcConnection` class and automatically call `LogIn()` there) Now your chat loop will simply be:

```
using (var pipe = Connection.OpenPipe()) {
    foreach (var message in pipe.ReadLines().Select(x => new IrcServerMessage(x))
        ProcessKnownMessages(message);
}
```

Now that your bot has *state* you may want to encapsulate those status into an `IrcClient` class (to handle basic log-in, keep track of open channels and so on.) In this way you will even be able to operate on multiple channels (or with multiple bots). Again a proof of concept:

```
using (var connection = new IrcConnection(CreateConnection))
using (var client = new IrcClient(connection) {
using (var bot = new IrcBot(client) {
    client.Open(); // Client will open connection if required
    bot.StartChatting();
}
```

As you can see if you **name things** your code will be more clear, easy to extend and feature-rich...

Also note that you should never catch `Exception` if you want to perform any recovery logic. Will you attempt a new server connection if you get `OutOfMemoryException`? What if you have `AccessViolationException`? Note that for logging purposes you may also want to *flatten* aggregate exceptions (and some others with an `InnerExceptions` - note it's plural - property.)

To retry at this outer level may be useful but you should carefully choose which exceptions you may ignore. For example:

```
try {
}
catch (Exception e) when (IsNotCriticalException(e)) {
}
```

Also note that in some circumstances you may want to ignore some exceptions (let's also introduce parsing exceptions like `ServerMessageFormatException`) but you have to *know* them otherwise you will not have a reliable software but a software that reliably repeatedly fails. Having specific exceptions will also help you to test failure scenarios: if your test will pass with `[ExpectedException(typeof(Exception))]` you will never be sure if it passed because you correctly handled that scenario or because your code is faulty and it generated `NullReferenceException`...

Comment: @tym32167 is this what you mean? ;-D Good job Adriano +1 ;-) but for this _micro_ app perhaps a little bit over engineered.

Comment: @t3chb0t I agree, of course OP code has to be "reduced" to fit question size then I'm always in doubt about how big his application is. For a _true_ IRC bot I'd start immediately with a more complex implementation, overhead is small (IMO) compared to time you will save just few days later ;)

Comment: I have to admit, that this general idea of separating all of the small tasks is what I've personally wanted to do with my project, and I love the way this looks. But wow would I be in over my head with how you were describing all that... I can never find good practical code like this in tutorials or what not.